# iText API Details for PDF validation

Tags: itext

I am gonna work on a casestudy, where I have a requirement to validate the PDF with certain standards(eg. check whether the contents in the PDF is of particular font,font size, logo position). So I just want to confirm whether using iTEXT I can get these kind of PDF specifications ? IF yes, what is the API used in iTEXT for doing it?

NOTE : Is there any other tool in market which does this kind of functionality ?

Answer (score 2):

As iText allows you to directly access all the PDF objects (dictionaries, arrays, streams, ...), it offers you the tools you need. But don't underestimate your task. Depending on the criteria you have to check, you may have quite a lot of work ahead.

E.g. if your criteria include that all text has to use a single given font, you can simply parse the whole document text and check the fonts. If on the other hand you have to differentiate between e.g. headings and standard text, you need to introduce some heuristics for that as generally headers are not marked as headers.

How good must your checks be? Does it suffice if the font dictionary has the required name entry or do you actually need to check that the font (possibly an embedded font subset) indeed is the required font?

You mention a logo position. How do you recognize the logo (in contrast to other drawings or images)?

...

Thus, iText can be used as a base but you will have to do quite a lot of thinking beforehand. If you decide to seriously use iText, I would propose you consult [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/).

There are other PDF libraries and tools available, too, both free (either as in free beer or as in free speach) and commercial, which offer a framework for PDF analysis. I'm mostly using iText and, therefore, do not know those other ones in depth.

Ceterum censeo, you should definitively have a look at the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (especially chapters 8 and 9 on graphics and text) to get a feeling for what PDF contains and what not.